# VBA: Is it possible to en/decode alias function name (Alias "CreateFileW" -> Alias Enc(182893))

Tags: vba, ms-office, obfuscation, declare

Is it possible to change load function name on declare line?

```
'CreateFileA = CreateFileB
'HANDLE CreateFileA(
'  LPCSTR                lpFileName,
'  DWORD                 dwDesiredAccess,
'  DWORD                 dwShareMode,
'  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
'  DWORD                 dwCreationDisposition,
'  DWORD                 dwFlagsAndAttributes,
'  HANDLE                hTemplateFile
');

Private Declare PtrSafe Function HP_CRT Lib "KERNEL32" Alias "CreateFileW"(ByVal name As String, ByVal aces As Long, ByVal shar As Long, ByVal satr As LongPtr, ByVal cdep As Long, ByVal fatr As Long, ByVal hand As Long) As LongPtr
```

to

```
Function LoadFunction(mode)
    return Decrypt(mode)
End Function
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HP_CRT Lib "KERNEL32" Alias LoadFunction("W")(ByVal name As String, ByVal aces As Long, ByVal shar As Long, ByVal satr As LongPtr, ByVal cdep As Long, ByVal fatr As Long, ByVal hand As Long) As LongPtr
```

or

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HP_CRT Lib "KERNEL32" Alias "---"(ByVal name As String, ByVal aces As Long, ByVal shar As Long, ByVal satr As LongPtr, ByVal cdep As Long, ByVal fatr As Long, ByVal hand As Long) As LongPtr
Sub CreateCase
    HP_CRT = GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("Kernel32"), "CreateFileW")
End Sub
```

Is there any possibility? or Impossible?
I am using MS-Office 2013 x64 on Windows 10 RS5

Comment: No, you cannot do that. But the function will not be resolved until you call it, so if you know that a function may not exist, then check for its existence before calling it.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you. Is there any other way to use `CreateFile` or other API functions?

Comment: You can create/find a type library that has them declared and reference that library from the project references. Or you could get the function pointer via `GetProcAddress`, construct an ASM thunk in memory that calls it with parameters and call the thunk with `CallWindowProc`. But it would be better to understand [why you are trying to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) in the first place.

Comment: I want to copy all the content of word document to specific file. But I cannot use "CreateFileA/W", because windows defender does not allow to use these functions. Please give some example of your comment.

Comment: Use the Word's `SaveAs` method? Use the VBA's [`FileCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filecopy-statement)? Use the VBA's [`Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) and [`Put`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/put-statement)? Not going to go with the ASM route, no.